# All my application run as admin rights

Tags: windows

for some reason all application or anything on my laptop has admin rights even tho i choose not to run as admin, for example, if i run notepad, chrome, it askes me for admin rights, im pretty sure the check on "Run as admin" on those are disabled... Even when i try to download a random .rar on internet, openning that random .rar also ask me for admin rights! How do i fix this problem? I dont want to reset because of personal reasons. Thank you.

My UAC setting is at second from the top and the laptop is safe from viruses i have Malwarebytes and Windows defender always running and i scan them regularly.

Comment: Does this also happen when booting in Safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

User Account Control setting is too high possibly:

1 Open the Control Panel (icons view), and click/tap on the User Accounts icon.

2 Click/tap on the Change User Account Control settings link.

3 If prompted by UAC, click/tap on Yes.

4 Move the slider up or down to the setting for how you want to be notified by UAC, and click/tap on OK. (see screenshots below)

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3577-change-user-account-control-uac-settings-windows-10-a.html

UAC could be set in Local Group Policy: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-group-policy-and-registry-key-settings#user-account-control-behavior-of-the-elevation-prompt-for-standard-users

Comment: @MyLinh - You shoud edit your question and mention it in that case.